$L^{1}$-convergence to steady states for an advection-diffusion equation on the half real line
I consider the following problem on the half real line
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t = u_{xx} + u_x, & \quad t > 0, \, x > 0, \\[2mm]
-u_x|_{x=0} = u|_{x=0}, & \quad t > 0, \, x = 0, \\[2mm]
u|_{t=0} = u_0, & \quad t = 0, \, x > 0,
\end{cases}\label{1}\tag{$\star$}
$$
where $u_0$ is nonnegative, bounded and compactly supported.
This problem preserves the $L^{1}$-norm of $u_0$, that is $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^*_+)}=\Vert u_0 \Vert_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^*_+)}$ for any $t>0$, and owns nonnegative steady states of the form
$$
U_\lambda(x) = \lambda e^{-x},
$$
where $\lambda\geq 0$ is the mass of $U_\lambda$.

I want to show that, for $\lambda=\Vert u_0 \Vert_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^*_+)}$, we have
$$
\boxed{\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \Vert u(t,\cdot) - U_\lambda \Vert_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^*_+)} = 0}
$$
by using entropy methods.

I tried the relative entropy
$$
H(t) : = \int_0^\infty u(t,x) \log \Big(  \frac{u(t,x)}{U_\lambda(x)}  \Big)   dx.
$$
For this entropy, I get for the dissipation
$$
\begin{align}
   \frac{d}{dt}H (t) & = - \int_0^\infty  \Bigg(  \frac{u_x}{\sqrt{u}} +\sqrt{u}  \Bigg)^{2}  dx
    = - I(u|U_\lambda) \leq 0,
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
I(u|U_\lambda) = \int_0^\infty  u(t,x) \Bigg[ \partial_x \log \Big(  \frac{u(t,x)}{U_\lambda(x)}  \Big) \Bigg]^{2}  dx
$$
stands for the Fisher information.
This basically tells me that this entropy $H(t)$ dissipates but I have no idea on how to prove the convergence of $H$ to $0$ --- this fact would solve my problem thanks to Csiszár-Kullback inequality that basically says that $\Vert u(t,\cdot) - U_\lambda \Vert_{L^{1}}^{2}\leq k \times H(t)$.
For the following problem
$$
\begin{cases}
v_t = v_{xx} + (x v)_x, & \quad t > 0, \, x > 0, \\[2mm]
-v_x|_{x=0} = 0, & \quad t > 0, \, x = 0, \\[2mm]
v|_{t=0} = v_0, & \quad t = 0, \, x > 0,
\end{cases}\label{2}\tag{$\star\star$}
$$
we can do similar computations to prove the convergence towards Gaussian steady states
$$
V_\lambda(x) = \lambda e^{-x^{2}/2}
$$
by using the log-Sobolev inequality that gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt}H (t) \leq - I(v|V_\lambda) \leq - k \times H (t),
$$
and therefore, $H(t)\leq H(0) e^{-k t} \to 0$.
However, this log-Sobolev inequality does not apply in case \eqref{1} since (if I have correctly understood) the potential
$$-\log (U_\lambda) (x) = x - \log (\lambda) $$
is not convex while in case \eqref{2},
$$-\log (V_\lambda) (x) = \frac{x^2}{2} - \log (\lambda) $$
is convex.
Any ideas or suggestions are welcome!

You wrote "by using entropy methods" in bold. Why is it important for you to use entropy methods for this problem?

Yes, actually continuation arguments may be used to reach an explicit solution and then the $L^{1}$ convergence follows. $(\star)$ arises from a more complex problem for which explicit solutions cannot be obtained. That's why I want to completely understand $(\star)$ with entropy methods.

Thanks for your reply! Is your more complex problem linear or nonlinear? In the linear case, one can often also use operator semigroup methods to show the convergence without explicitly computing the solution. (For instance, this also works for the equation in the question; but whether it works in your more complex problem depends on the problem, of course.)

In the more complex problem, first line of $(\star)$ becomes
$$
u_t = u_{xx} + [(1+f(t) x) u]_x,
$$
where f is a smooth function that vanishes exponentially fast as $t$ goes to $\infty$.
Do you still think that the semigroup theory could work for this kind of non-autonomous problem?

Good question. Semigroup theory can certainly be used to study some non-autonomous problems. But the methods that I have in mind for treating the long-term behaviour might not work in this case. I'll have to think about it. By the way, does $f$ depend on $x$? It seems that $f$ destroys the mass perservation property, unless $f(t)$ vanishes at $x=0$ for all $t$.

(Just for the sake of completeness I wrote down the semigroup argument in the autonomous case in an answer.)

Thank you very much for your answer! Concerning the more complex problem, the mass is preserved since it is $f(t) \times x $ that vanishes at $x=0$. Do you think that a $C_0$-semigroup still exists for this more complex problem (let's call it $(\star \star \star)$)?
I am also wondering about the validity of a Duhamel formula with the semigroup $T$, seeing $(f(t)xu)_x$ as a source term --- this could require a priori estimates on this source term.

Ah, I see - I overlooked the $x$ after $f(t)$. The non-autonomous equation will not be governed by a $C_0$-semigroup, but probably by a non-autonomous evolution family. The problem I see is rather that typical convergence theorems for $C_0$-semigroups don't apply to non-autonomous evolution families (even on finite dimensional spaces).

Here's a solution by semigroup methods (rather than entropy methods) - but I don't know if the argument can be adapted to the non-autonomous situaion mentioned by the OP in the comments.
The solution of the equation is given by $u(t) = T(t)u_0$ for all $t \ge 0$, where $T = (T(t))_{t \ge 0}$ is a stochastic $C_0$-semigroup on $L^1(0,\infty)$ ("stochastic" means that for every initial function $0 \le u_0 \in L^1(0,\infty)$ one has $T(t)u_0 \ge 0$ and $\|T(t)u_0\| = \|u_0\|$ for all $t \ge 0$).
As pointed out in the question, the semigroup $T$ has a fixed point in $L^1$ which is $>0$ almost everywhere.
Moreover, one can show that each of the operators is, for $t > 0$, given by integration against an integral kernel (for general elliptic operators on $d$-dimensional domains an argument for this can be found in Section 5.2 of this article by Wolfgang Arendt; in the one-dimensional situation discussed here, one can probably find an easier argument).
So to sum up, the semigroup $T$ is positive and contractive (since it is stochastic), it has a fixed point that is $>0$ almost everywhere and it consists of operators given by integral kernels.
This implies that $T(t)$ converges strongly as $t \to \infty$. This is a result from the 1980s that goes back to Günther Greiner. See for instance Theorem 1 in this article by Moritz Gerlach and myself for a quite straightforward proof (the article also contains references to more general results and to Greiner's original proof).
